# PDF files custom context menu not appearing

Tags: registry

I want to create a custom context menu (shell) entry in Windows 10. I tried to add the entry to the following keys:

```
shell entry properties for all:
@="Open with Adobe Acrobat Pro 2017"
"Icon"="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Adobe\\Acrobat 2017\\Acrobat\\Acrobat.exe\""
"Position"="Top"

\command for all:
@="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Adobe\\Acrobat 2017\\Acrobat\\Acrobat.exe\" \"%1\""


Tried keys:

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.pdf\shell\OpenWithAcrobat]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.pdf\shell\OpenWithAcrobat\command]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Acrobat.Document.2017\shell\OpenWithAcrobat]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Acrobat.Document.2017\shell\OpenWithAcrobat\command]


[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\.pdf\shell\OpenWithAcrobat]
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\.pdf\shell\OpenWithAcrobat\command]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Acrobat.Document.2017\shell\OpenWithAcrobat]
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Acrobat.Document.2017\shell\OpenWithAcrobat\command]


[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\.pdf\shell\OpenWithAcrobat]
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\.pdf\shell\OpenWithAcrobat\command]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Acrobat.Document.2017\shell\OpenWithAcrobat]
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Acrobat.Document.2017\shell\OpenWithAcrobat\command]
```

But it won't appear in the context menu.

Background: I use another program to view PDF files, because it's much more performant and I use Acrobat just for editing files or filling forms.

Can someone explain what the problem is?

Comment: Since it works for other types, I assume it's related to the `.pdf` key not having a default value pointing to the file type definition key. I tried adding one manually but that does not seem to help. It must be around somewhere, since there's a proper description for the file type in explorer, but I don't know where it's pulling that data from.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating the `\shell\your context menu entry\command` structure directly inside `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.pdf`. You might have to create the `.pdf` key.

What I've written below still works, but I don't recommend doing that, as it's more complicated and easy to break.

---

It appears `.pdf` and some other extensions are getting special treatment in Windows 10. The `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.pdf` default value is empty; the key name for the file type is being loaded from a different place. You need to check the `ProgId` value in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.pdf\UserChoice`, it will contain the the current file type identifier. On a fresh install it should be `MSEdgePDF`. You then locate that key inside `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`, and add your `shell\Something\command` structure there.

Unfortuately this means you have to do it again when the user changes the *open with* default program (since it will associate the `.pdf` extension with a different key), but afaict from my limited research this is intentional.